# Create dynamic input text of group and options and transfer it to php

Tags: php, javascript, html, dynamic, voting

I'm writing simple remote voting system in PHP and I have problem with control of dynamic options and groups in php form.

I would like to have something like this, but.... (asks are at the bottom of my post):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/97450434.png/

**I have the following code:**

html:

```
<fieldset style="width:99%; float:left">
         <div id="dynamicInput">
              Group 1<br><input type="text" name="myGroupInputs[]">
                 <div id="dynamicInput" style="margin-left:50px;">
                      Option 1<br><input type="text" name="myOptionsInputs[]">
                 </div>
         </div>
             <input type="button" value="Add another group" onClick="addGroup('dynamicInput');">
             <input type="button" value="Add another option" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">         
</fieldset>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​js:

```
var counter_option = 1;
var limit_option = 10;
var counter_group = 1;
var limit_group = 10;
function addInput(divName){

     if (counter_option == limit_option)  {
           alert('You cannot add more options.');
     }
    else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<font style='margin-left:50px;'>Option</font> " + (counter_option+ 1) + " <br><input type='text' style='margin-left:50px;' name='myOptionsInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter_option++;
     }
}
function addGroup(divName){

     if (counter_group == limit_group)  {
           alert('You cannot add more groups.');
     }
    else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Group " + (counter_group + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myGroupInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter_group++;
     }
}
```

**1. How to edit this code to have dependence each option to the right group and reset the counter of options to 0 if I will add another group? 

Group1, Option1, Option2; 

Group2, Option1, Option2; etc.**

**2. How to put these values later to the php variables, array or sth... - I would like to insert these values to the database (php
   script). Script must knows that the option corresponding to the right
   group.**

My database has two tables:
Groups and Options(FK to Group)

Link to jsfiddle edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnyyK/

Please, help....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multidimensional array.

Change the names of your groups to:

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
  Group 1
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="groups[0][name]">
  <div id="dynamicInput" style="margin-left:50px;">
    Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="groups[0][options][]">
  </div>
</div>
```

On adding a new group increase the `groups`' index e.g.

```
"<input type='text' name='groups[" + counter_group + "][name]'>"
```

```
"<input type='text' name='groups[" + counter_group + "][options][]'>"
```

You should be able to process the groups in PHP this way:

```
foreach ($_POST['groups'] as $group) {
  $name = $group['name'];
  $options = $group['options'];
  ...
}
```

---

### UPDATE

To clear confusions, here is the actual code:

```
var counter_group = 0;
var limit_group = 10;
var counter_option = 0;
var limit_option = 10;

var addInput = function(divName) {
  if (counter_option == limit_option - 1) {
    alert('You cannot add more options.');
  } else {
    counter_option++;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<font style='margin-left:50px;'>Option</font> " + (counter_option + 1) + "<input type='text' name='groups[" + counter_group + "][options][]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  }
}

var addGroup = function(divName) {
  if (counter_group == limit_group - 1) {
    alert('You cannot add more groups.');
  } else {
    counter_group++;
    counter_option = -1;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Group " + (counter_group + 1) + "<input type='text' name='groups[" + counter_group + "][name]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. The idea with multidimensional array is very good.... - thanks, but it doesn't work ... :(  I don't know why...

Comment: @atrzcinski, I had some typos though. Now, It's tested

Comment: @Aleksander, When I'm sending form like this:
http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2152/40707389.png
ADD TO DB BUTTON - 'echo' these values only. 
I'm receiving following response:
http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/6923/94204901.png

Comment: @atrzcinski, use `print_r()` not `echo` in this case. Unless you show what is the status of your code now, I won't be able to help

Comment: @atrzcinski, `addGroup()` and `addInput()` `innerHTML` are messed up. Answer updated

Comment: @Aleksander, YES !!! :) everything works ok, but can you give me simple code to insert these values to table[database]? How to get the values from these Arrays?

Comment: @atrzcinski, I think that's unrelated to this question

Comment: @Aleksander, second bold question at the bottom of my 1st post, could we move this discussion to chat?